# How to manage to render my table when redux data changed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-table, saga

I use tanstack react table.
my short version of code is below

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
import {
  ColumnFiltersState,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFacetedMinMaxValues,
  getFacetedRowModel,
  getFacetedUniqueValues,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getGroupedRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel,
  GroupingState,
  useReactTable,
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  Row,
  getExpandedRowModel,
  Table
} from '@tanstack/react-table';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CustomTable from './components/CustomTable';

type TableProps<TData> = {
  rows?: TData[]
  columns: ColumnDef<TData>[]
  renderSubComponent?: (props: { row: Row<TData> }) => React.ReactElement
  getRowCanExpand?: (row: Row<TData>) => boolean,
  pageLimit?: number,
  className?: string,
  filters?: [],
  formatData?: Function,
  setInstance?: Function,
  apiLoad?: Function,
  dispatch?: any,
  apiLoadAction?: any,
  dataSelector?: any,
}

type dataProp<TData> = {
  meta?: {
    last_page: number,
    page: number,
    total: number,
  },
  data?: TData[]
}

const TableGrid = ({
  rows,
  apiLoad,
  columns,
  pageLimit,
  className,
  filters,
  formatData,
  setInstance,
  renderSubComponent,
  getRowCanExpand,
  dispatch,
  apiLoadAction,
  dataSelector
}: TableProps<any>) => {
  let data: dataProp<any> = {};
  let table: Table<any>;
  const rerender = useReducer(() => ({}), {})[1]
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState<any>([])
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState<any>([]);
  const [{ pageIndex, pageSize }, setPagination] = useState({
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: pageLimit || 10
  });

  const defaultData = useMemo(() => [], []);

  const pagination = useMemo(
    () => ({
      pageIndex,
      pageSize
    }),
    [pageIndex, pageSize]
  );

  const queryParams = useSearchParams();
  const currentPage: number = +(queryParams.get("page") || 1);

  if (dataSelector) {
    data = formatData ? formatData(useSelector(dataSelector)) : useSelector(dataSelector);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    loadData();
  }, [currentPage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, [data]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    if (apiLoadAction) {
      dispatch(apiLoadAction({ page: currentPage, count: pageSize, ...filters }));
    }
  }

  table = useReactTable({
    data: rows ? rows : (data?.data ?? defaultData),
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    state: {
      pagination,
      columnFilters,
      sorting,
    },
    manualPagination: true,
    pageCount: rows ? rows?.length : (data?.meta?.total ?? -1), // maybe need to be fixed
    onPaginationChange: setPagination,
    getRowCanExpand,
    getExpandedRowModel: getExpandedRowModel(),
    debugTable: true,
    debugHeaders: true,
    debugColumns: true,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setInstance && setInstance({
      table,
      loadData
    });
  }, [])


  return (
    <CustomTable table={table} renderSubComponent={renderSubComponent} />
  )
}

export default TableGrid;
```

when `currentPage` changed with the query parameter everything worked fine but when I changed data each time outside of this component and the redux state changed each time but the table shows always initialized values, not the new versions of `data` values.
`data = formatData ? formatData(useSelector(dataSelector)) : useSelector(dataSelector);`
I search a lot but didn't find any solution